# Getting crontab on MAC to run anaconda installed python script (module not found)

Tags: python, macos, path, cron, anaconda

I am trying to set up crontab for a script written in python which is intalled via Anaconda. The simple .py runs (it just loads a module for a demo) and can be run in terminal with python a.py .
The problem is getting crontab the path for python and imported modules.

I have been trying to set the PATH and PYTHONPATh to the python directory and also where pandas is located. I think this is a env issue but have no idea what that means. Any ideas?

The crontab is:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PYTHONPATH=/Users/Esel/anaconda3/bin/python
* * * * *  cd /Users/Esel/Documents/x/y/z && python a.py
```

The python (test) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 18 21:36:34 2019

@author: Esel
"""

import pandas

print('hello kitty')
# This is a test
```

Crontab mails the following statement:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 3, in 
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: Is there a module pandas for python3?

Comment: Does the module actually reside in `/Users/Esel/anaconda3/bin/python`?

Comment: module for pandas for python, yes. Python3? Not sure. I run py3.7 via anaconda/spyder so I assume that  pandas, which works in spyder and via terminal is somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an env.var, cd'ing to a directory, and calling an interpreter, all from crontab.

Under those circumstances, personally I'd find it more elegant to just create a small wrapper script (here called `pyscript`) that does all that, and call that script from crontab:

```
$> cat /home/me/bin/pyscript
#!/bin/bash
# a.py needs module pandas in /foo/bar
export PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar
cd /Users/Esel/Documents/x/y/z || exit
python a.py

$> chmod ug+rx /home/me/bin/pyscript

$> cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/me
...
* * * * *  /home/me/bin/pyscript
```

Answer (score 0):

With some ideas from a roadowl (thanx) and another SOverflow question (54564187) I think I got it running.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH/Users/Esel/anaconda3/bin:/Users/Esel/anaconda3/condabin:/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Users/Esel/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
* * * * *  cd /Users/Esel/Documents/x/y/z && python a.py
```

The path came from

```
echo $PATH
```